# Cursor does not change on mousedown and drag (IE11)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cursor

I am trying to implement the "pseudo-drag": you drag the element, but the element itself is not dragged, *it changes the cursor* in the needed area. But the bad thing is, that the cursor is not changed when the mouse is in the needed area. It changes only when you release the mouse in that area. If you watch the DOM inspector, *in code* change occures just when needed, but **on the screen** it changes only when you release the mouse button. I've done a short example of a problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test drag</title>
 <script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
   var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
   var to = document.querySelector('#to');
   btn.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    to.style.cursor='wait';
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="from">
  <button id='btn'>DRAG ME!</button>
 </div>
 <div id="to" style="height: 150px;background-color: aqua;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This problem was reported on IE11.

So the question is: is there a way to make cursor changed when the cursor is dragged (LMB is pressed) to the desired area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of weird, but this should work in IE11 and in Chrome.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var to = document.getElementById('to');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
  if(event.target.id === 'btn') {
    
    // for Chrome
    to.style.cursor='wait';
    
    // for IE11
    to.classList.add('wait');
    to.focus();
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
  
  // for Chrome
  to.style.cursor='default';
  
  // for IE11
  to.blur();
  to.classList.remove('wait');
})
```

```css
.wait:hover {
  cursor: wait;
}
```

```html
<div id="from">
  <button id='btn'>DRAG ME!</button>
</div>
<div id="to" style="height: 150px;background-color: aqua;"></div>
```